# img.onload doesn't work inside the for loop

Tags: javascript, loops, canvas, html5-canvas

I want to draw an image to every canvas that I created. but when I run the code, the last one was drawn.

[image: Those canvas are empty]

I think this problem caused by for loop. because img.onload takes some time to load. and here's my code:

```
this.difficulty = $('#difficult').val();

var nSquares = parseInt($('#difficult').val()) * parseInt($('#difficult').val());

var pieceSize = 500 / this.difficulty;
var index = 1;

var dy = 0;
for(var i = 1; i <= this.difficulty;i++){
    var dx = 0;
    for(var j = 1; j <= this.difficulty;j++){
        var square = $('<canvas></canvas>');
        square.attr('id',"p" + index);
        square.attr('width',pieceSize);
        square.attr('height',pieceSize);

        $('#puzzle').append(square);

        var context = $('#p'+index)[0].getContext('2d');

        var img = new Image();

        img.onload = function(){
            context.drawImage(this,0,0,pieceSize,pieceSize);
        }

        img.src = this.image;


        index++;
        dx += pieceSize;

        console.log(dx+' '+dy);
    }
    dy += pieceSize;
}
```

Comment: you keep overwriting `img` on every iteration. that leaves the JS engine free to destroy the previous object, since it's not used anymore, and replace it with a new one.

Comment: it not need a load time. Try it `var img = new Image(); context.drawImage(img,0,0,pieceSize,pieceSize);`

Comment: @OnurBoz, if only comments could be downvoted... **You absolutely need to wait that any image has loaded before being able to do whatever with it.**

Comment: @MarcB The real variable being overwritten in this snippet is `context` since OP correctly uses `this` in the callback.

Comment: @OnurBoz youre code doesn't work.

Comment: No answer? seriously?